# получить все все сочетания из "110"

Tags: python, комбинаторика

Есть массив по типу [1, 1, 0]. Нужно получить все сочетания из двух единиц и одного нуля, но без повторов (пробовал itertools.permutations("110", 3), но он выдает "повторы" по типу 110=110. Нужно: 011 101 110 и больше не надо). На с++ есть next_permutations, можно ли что-то подобное сделать на python?

Comment: `set(permutations("110", 3))` ?

Comment: Что предполагается делать со ста миллионами комбинаций?

Comment: для взлома шифра нужно перебрать варианты, обработать их и выбрать самый вероятный

Answer (score 2):

Переустановки элементов без повторов:

```
from itertools import permutations

print(set(permutations("110", r=3)))
# {('1', '0', '1'), ('0', '1', '1'), ('1', '1', '0')}

items = [''.join(x) for x in set(permutations("110", r=3))]
print(items)  # ['110', '011', '101']
```